# What's purpose of the Internal`ToEquivalenceClass

Tags: undocumented, internals

There is a *kernel* function `` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass ``.I don't know how to use it.There are some right example right to run

```
Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[{1, 2, 3}]

(* {1, 2, 3} *)

Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[9]
(* 9 *)

Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[{1, 2., 3}, 9]
(* {1, 2., 3} *)
```

But the `` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[{1, 2., 3}, {5, 6}] `` will give a error information

> [image]

And we can find a option of it.

```
Internal`ToEquivalenceClass // Options
```

> `{Heads -> True}`

Can anybody the usage and the intention about this function?

Comment: Umm...it is in `Internal\`` context.

Comment: You demonstrate that you are clueless about what the function does, so why do you want to use it? And if you don't want to use it, but are just curious about it, why should we spend our time trying to find out for you? As Daniel Lichtblau points out, it is the `Internal` context; not meant for users.

Comment: @m_goldberg,Daniel Lichtblau I have opened a discuss in *Meta.SE* [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/is-the-discussion-about-undocument-function-acclaimed-in-se).If most people think I should not take such topic.I will delete it and stop to talk these undocumented question.

Comment: @m_goldberg This question is like one my earlier [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/can-anyone-guess-what-internalradicalmemberq-does) about an undocumented function, driven purely out of curiosity.  My opinion is that this is a perfectly fine question, should not be closed, and that others can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: @QuantumDot. That's a perfectly valid opinion, but mine happens to be different.

Answer (score 17):

`` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[expr, tol] `` is used to replace floating point numbers in an expression with their equivalence class representatives according to the specified tolerance.

For an example, using machine precision, consider

```
nums = {0.33000000000000004, 0.33000000000000007, 0.33000000000000010};
```

The first two numbers are equivalent under the default tolerance which allows a difference in the last binary digit

```
Gather[nums, Function[Abs[#1 - #2] < 2^-53]] // InputForm

(* {{0.33, 0.33000000000000007}, {0.3300000000000001}} *)
```

so `` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[nums] `` which is the same as

`` Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[nums, N[Log[10, 2]]] ``

returns

```
(* {0.33000000000000007, 0.33000000000000007, 0.3300000000000002} *)
```

As the tolerance increases, the equivalence classes become larger: if another bit of tolerance is allowed, all three numbers are considered equivalent

```
Internal`ToEquivalenceClass[nums, N[Log[10, 2^2]]] // InputForm

(* {0.33000000000000007, 0.33000000000000007, 0.33000000000000007} *)
```

Comment: As your answer,it is same the function ``Internal`CompareNumeric`` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140528/how-does-internalcomparenumeric-work).Though I think [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QjYap.png) is little unexpected..